# Spearman rank correlation in Python with ties

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, correlation

I want to compute the [spearman rank correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman's_rank_correlation_coefficient) using Python and most likely scipy implementation (scipy.stats.spearmanr).

The data at hand looks e.g., the following way (dictionaries):

```
{a:0.3, b:0.2, c:0.2} and {a:0.5, b:0.6, c:0.4}
```

To now pass it over to the spearman module, I would assign them ranks, if I am correct (descending):

```
[1,2,3] and [2,1,3]
```

So now I want to consider ties, so would I now use for the first vector:

```
[1,2,2] or [1,2.5,2.5]
```

Basically, is this whole concept correct and how to handle ties for such dictionary-based data.

As suggested by @Jaime the spearmanr function works with values, but why is this behavior possible:

```
In [5]: spearmanr([0,1,2,3],[1,3,2,0])
Out[5]: (-0.39999999999999997, 0.59999999999999998)

In [6]: spearmanr([10,7,6,5],[0.9,0.5,0.6,1.0])
Out[6]: (-0.39999999999999997, 0.59999999999999998)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should include a brief explanation and a link to what the 'spearman rank correlation' is. also, [what have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`scipy.stats.spearmanr` will take care of computing the ranks for you, you simply have to give it the data in the correct order:

```
>>> scipy.stats.spearmanr([0.3, 0.2, 0.2], [0.5, 0.6, 0.4])
(0.0, 1.0)
```

If you have the ranked data, you can call `scipy.stats.pearsonr` on it to get the same result. And as the examples below show, either of the ways you have tried will work, although I think `[1, 2.5, 2.5]` is more common. Also, scipy uses zero-based indexing, so the ranks internally used will be more like `[0, 1.5, 1.5]`:

```
>>> scipy.stats.pearsonr([1, 2, 2], [2, 1, 3])
(0.0, 1.0)
>>> scipy.stats.pearsonr([1, 2.5, 2.5], [2, 1, 3])
(0.0, 1.0)
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that it's also working with the plain values. Nevertheless, I am curious how it works internally. How does the method know that if I am passing ranks those are no values? Because, if I am not completely confused at the moment, the rankings would look different.

Comment: @ph_singer They are different functions. `spearmanr` will turn whatever you give it into ranks, and then compute a Pearson correlation coefficient on that. `pearsonr` on the other hand computes the Pearson correlation coefficient directly.

Comment: I added an example to my original question, because I can't post it here in this comment. Please take a look at it. thanks!